# Kinetics of gas molecule

Tags: classical-mechanics

In the explanation of the nature of gases we use the kinetic formula $PV=1/3(mnc)$
where $p$ is pressure, $v$ volume, $m$ mass, $n$ number of molecules and $c$ means root mean square velocity. But in its explanation I don't understand why everyone uses time to measure the change of momentum of a particular molecule, and in that case everyone uses the time for the molecule to go from one side to another, but it is true that the molecule has a constant velocity. 
In order to prove the equation we firstly think there r some gas in a cubic container.Lets think about a single  gas 
molecule.it is moving with it's kinetic energy.suppose the leangth of the cubic container is $l$ and the molecule needs t second to reach from one side of the container to other.suppose the molecule doesn't hit other molecule bt the wall.so before hitting the wall its velocity doesn't change.bt within short time its velocity changes its direction after hitting the wall and moves 
towards the opposite side of the container.now i want to measure the action and reaction force by using the change of momentum.

When that hits the wall the direction of velocity changes within a short time limit to 0 as it is a spontaneous collision, so the change of momentum must be measured by using this time not the time for the molecule to go from one side of the wall of a container to the other side. Am I right or not?

Comment: If u dont understand me then look it at wikipedia 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gas

Comment: Hi, I tried to edit your post, but I am still not sure what exactly you are trying to ask. You write a formula in which there is no time, and then you start talking about everyone using some time - I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Well in what you are describing, normally the interest is to show how pressure stays constant and equidistributed, not to show how the wall heats up. In fact if the wall heats up, the gas would be losing energy, and the particles would not be bouncing elastically on the walls, but inelastically. I think you are understanding a different point that the one being explained.